# what's messing with my cross browser capabilities here?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I'm kind of new to Javascript, and somebody helped me with this script, it works great on Chrome but it doesn't work in Firefox, and haven't tested it in IE yet but I want it to work in all browsers, and I don't really know that much on jQuery as to translate it

```
function displayTotal()
{

     var tableRows = document.getElementById('budgetTable').getElementsByTagName('tr');
     var totalDays = tableRows.length - 3; //Don't count the header rows and the Total rows

     var totalPrice = 0;

    var price = filterNum(document.getElementById( 'txtPrice' ).value);
     var totalField = document.getElementById('txtTotal');


     var tempHours = 0;
     var tempTotal = 0; 

     for(var i = 0; i < totalDays; i++)
     {

         tempHours = document.getElementById("end" + i).value - document.getElementById("start" + i).value;
         tempTotal = tempHours * price;

         document.getElementById("total" + i).innerHTML = formatCurrency(tempTotal);
         totalPrice += tempTotal;
         console.log(i, "Start:" + document.getElementById("start" + i).value, "End:" + document.getElementById("end" + i).value, "Hours:" + tempHours, "Total:" + tempTotal);
     }

    totalField.value = formatCurrency(totalPrice);

 }

function addRowToTable()
{
    var tbl = document.getElementById('budgetTable');
    var lastRow = tbl.rows.length - 2;
    var iteration = lastRow;
    var entry = iteration - 1; //because we started with day0, etc 
    var row = tbl.insertRow(lastRow);

    // day cell
    var cellDay = row.insertCell(0);
    cellDay.appendChild(createInput('text','day' + entry, '', displayTotal));

    // start cell
    var cellStart = row.insertCell(1);
    cellStart.appendChild(createInput('text','start' + entry, 0, displayTotal));

    // end cell
    var cellEnd = row.insertCell(2);
    cellEnd.appendChild(createInput('text','end' + entry, 0, displayTotal));

    // total cell
    var cellTotal = row.insertCell(3);
    cellTotal.id = 'total' + entry;

}

function createInput(type, id, value, action)
{   
    var el = document.createElement('input');
    el.type = type;
    el.id = id;
    el.value = value;
    el.onkeyup = action;
    return el;
}

function filterNum(str)
{
    re = /^\$|,/g;
    // remove "$" and ","
    return str.replace(re, "");
}

function formatCurrency(num)
{
    num = isNaN(num) || num === '' || num === null ? 0.00 : num;
    return parseFloat(num).toFixed(2);
}
```

Any help will be welcomed as I really don't know where I'm missing then point here.

EDIT: ok, this is weird, but on Firefox, when I enable firebug to try to debug it,... it works.

Comment: @la_f0ka: what error are u getting in Firefox? Have you used firebug before?

Comment: 'totalDays = tableRows.length-3' is superfluous.  If you want to skip the 'header' rows, define a thead and tbody.  Then, you can either put an id on tbody and get those rows or getElementById('budgetTable').getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].length

Comment: “It doesn't work” is *never* a good error description. Please tell what goes wrong, what the expected behaviour is and if you get error messages in the console.

Comment: I'm sorry, as I said I'm new to js so I haven't debugged it, but I'll try. In firefox it just doesn't multiply the txtPrice and shows the total when I add fields

Comment: you're the greatest js coder of all times. I commented console.log and now it works perfectly in chrome, firefox and explorer, thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
tempHours = document.getElementById("end" + i).value - document.getElementById("start" + i).value;
document.getElementById("total" + i).innerHTML
```

The output any element attribute (such as element.value and element.innerHTML) is always a string.  You can only perform mathematical functions on numbers.  If the string only contains 'number characters' you can use parseInt() or parseFloat to convert them

```
console.log(); // Is a Firebug function.  Try commenting it out.
```

Comment: That shouldn't cause any problems, as JavaScript automatically converts types when needed.

Comment: I stand corrected; addition is really the only case it can't tell whether to use a number or string.  It's still good practice to convert your values to numbers anyway.